# How to get variables/functions from a child GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, children, gameobject

**Hello!** I am trying to make a room that will generate a random Layout from a list and get a variable from that layout. I have had some trouble with this since the layout is not there from the start of the game, and I have been working on this problem for a few days now. Currently, the "Room" GameObject searches it's children for the ones tagged "Layouts", then, after finding *that* GameObject, the code gets the "waves" variable from the Layouts component of the Layout. The code is here:

```
foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
   if (child.tag == "Layouts")
   {
      layout = child.gameObject.GetComponent<Layout>();
   }
}
layout.testFunction();
totalKillsNeeded = layout.waves;
```

When I run the code, nothing happens. No errors or anything. testFunction doesn't run, despite my Visual Studio showing the reference between the two scripts, and totalKillsNeeded returns 0 despite me checking and seeing that layout.waves equals 1 or 2. I have tried multiple methods of getting the Layout script, all of which have returned the same result. It is probably something small I havn't considered, but I still have not been able to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, please can you provide more code to make [mcve] with some example values.  The code above goes through all the child transforms, gets the last one and runs testfunction (should layout not be null) and totalkills would be set to whatever is in that last ones waves, or null.. are you getting warnings? errors?

Comment: It would be a good practice to add a `break;` after setting the layout in order  to exit the iteration, you may have more than one child containing the Layout component in your scene.

Comment: `GetComponentInChildren<>()`? Also `GetComponentsInChildren<>()` if there's more than one.

Comment: For some reason I can't edit, so I'll comment here. First @BugFinder: I know for a fact that for every room there will be one and only one, no more or less, as a child, and so waves would only get that value. I am also getting no errors or warnings as I said in the post. Next draco18s-no-longer-trusts-se, that is one of the methods I have already tried, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Consider using `if ( child.CompareTag("Layouts") )` for a slight efficiency advantage.

Comment: Please try again to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59649343/edit) the question to include a [mre]. Without one, we can only repeatedly ask you clarifying questions and it makes the answering process take much longer than it needs to and also increases the probability of miscommunication. What gets output if you put `Debug.Log("Iterating...");` before the loop and also `Debug.Log("Found: ' " + child.tag + " ' ");` at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: the code above looks fine, so, something isnt working you will need to add debug statements to prove that code runs, and look at the balues on the objects picked up

Comment: @BitWarrior Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Your code should work, but in case, try this. Here's ScriptA.cs, put this on the parent**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptA: MonoBehaviour
{
    int totalKillsNeeded = 0;
    ScriptB layout;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        foreach(Transform child in transform)
        {
            if(child.CompareTag("Layouts"))
            {
                layout = child.gameObject.GetComponent<ScriptB>();
            }
        }

        layout.testFunction();
        totalKillsNeeded = layout.waves;

        Debug.Log($"Total Kills needed: {totalKillsNeeded}, layout waves {layout.waves}");
    }
}
```

**And ScriptB.cs, put this on the Child game objects, and set the wave in inspector if needed**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptB: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int waves = 12;

    public void testFunction()
    {
        Debug.Log("Test Function Called, waves: {waves}");
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

[image]

**The hierarchy should look something like this:**

[image]

**If your last child has 0 waves, your for loop will only show the last one:**

[image]